# provide a simple response to a get request on a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to set up a webhook subscription on application A. Application A appends a query string to the submitted URL, `?validationCode=1234`.
To validate, my response must only be the code, 1234 in my example.

I am able to successfully set up the subscription to a webhook.site URL by modifying the response body, but I am unsuccessful in submitting just the validation code from the Wordpress site.

I have done some tests using postman, submitting the get request to both the webhook.site URL and my Wordpress endpoint.

Webhook site only returns the code `1234`. My script returns the code with double quotes at the beginning and end: `"1234"`

How do I modify my script to return just the raw code? Currently it appears to `json_encode()` the code when it responds to the incoming request.

Here is my code:

```
function bs_register_webhook_endpoint()
{
    register_rest_route('bliksem/v1', '/prismhr', array(
        'methods'  => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'bs_handle_webhook_endpoint',
    ));
}


/**
 * Handle the response
 */

function bs_handle_webhook_endpoint($request)
{

    $validation_token =  sanitize_text_field($request->get_param('validationToken'));

    header('Content-Type: text/plain');

    if ($validation_token) {
        header('Content-Type: text/plain');
        return $validation_token;
    }
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'bs_register_webhook_endpoint');
```

Here is the response in Postman when the get request is sent to a webhook site URL:

```
aa4UB5cHQBFJ4bWbLKK0aZ2G70CPT4
```

Here is the response in Postman when the get request is sent to my Wordpress site:

```
"aa4UB5cHQBFJ4bWbLKK0aZ2G70CPT4"
```

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#return-value: _"After your callback is called, the return value is then converted to JSON, and returned to the client."_ - a string value, converted to JSON, or course gets double quotes put around it.